# Angular with Breeze error Cannot call method of undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, crud, breeze

I'm testing sample CRUD using Angular and Breeze following sample ToDo project.
But for some reason I get error Cannot call method 'getAll'  of undefined.
(my odata is hosted on another localhost server, and CORS is enabled, I've tested it)

Here is my code:

Main.js:

```
var app = {};

app.adminMuscleGroup = angular.module('WebApp', []);
```

DataService:

```
app.adminMuscleGroup.dataService = (function (breeze, logger) {

    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });

    var servicename = 'http://localhost:23758/odata/';

    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(servicename);

    manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);

    var dataService = {
        getAll: getAll,

    };

    return dataService;

    function getAll() {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("MuscleGroup").orderBy("Name");

        return manager.executeQuery(query);
    }



})(breeze, app.logger);
```

Controller:

```
app.adminMuscleGroup.controller('AdminMuscleGroupCtrl', function($scope) {
    var dataService = window.app.dataService;
    var logger = window.app.logger;

    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.getAllMuscleGroups = function () {
        dataService.getAll()
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);
    };

    $scope.getAllMuscleGroups();

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        $scope.items = [];
        data.results.forEach(function (item) {
            $scope.items.push(item);
        });

        $scope.apply();

        logger.info("Fetched all Muscle Groups");
    }

    function queryFailed(error) {
        logger.error(error.message, "Query failed");
    }

}
```

And here is whole error:

```
ypeError: Cannot call method 'getAll' of undefined
    at Object.$scope.getAllMuscleGroups (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/app/AdminMuscleGroup/MuscleGroupController.js:10:21)
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/app/AdminMuscleGroup/MuscleGroupController.js:15:12)
    at invoke (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:2902:28)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:2914:23)
    at http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:4805:24
    at http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:4384:17
    at forEach (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:137:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:4369:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:4015:15)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:3920:30) angular.js:5754
(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was stupid mistake, I've changed this line:

```
var dataService = window.app.dataService;
```

into this:

```
var dataService = window.app.adminMuscleGroup.dataService;
```

Now it works

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject the dataService directly to the controller

```
app.adminMuscleGroup.controller('AdminMuscleGroupCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
    var dataService = window.app.dataService; // -> delete this
```

Comment: Now I get this error: `Error: Unknown provider: dataServiceProvider <- dataService`